# How to block until tkinter events can be processed

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

**EDIT: Possible solution below, can anyone confirm?**

I'm running tkinter in a thread, and attempting to use the `event_generate` technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276069/799222) to control its behaviour from other threads.  Clearly, once I have started a thread which sets up a `tkinter.Tk` instance and starts its mainloop, it is necessary to block until the mainloop has started before attempting to generate events.  The way I was trying to do this is as follows (python 3.2 code):

```
import tkinter
import threading

mainloop_started = threading.Event()

def tkinter_thread_stuff():
    global root
    root = tkinter.Tk()

    #[code that binds events with root.bind]

    root.after(0, mainloop_started.set)
    root.mainloop()

th = threading.Thread(target=tkinter_thread_stuff)
th.start()

mainloop_started.wait()

#[code that sends events to root with event_generate]
```

In other words, I am using `after` to cause the tkinter mainloop to set the `threading.Event` called `mainloop_started`, and my event-generating code starts by blocking until this event is set.  However, this seems to lead to a race condition - sometimes events generated quickly after `mainloop_started.wait()` are never processed by tkinter.  If I put a time delay in the `after` call (e.g. `root.after(1000, mainloop_started.set)`), this does not happen, so it looks like there is some time in between the point where tkinter calls the `after` callback, and the point at which it is able to receive events.  Does anyone know the correct way of blocking until tkinter can receive events?

PS: is it safe to run the tkinter mainloop inside a thread like this?  I know I can't interfere directly with root or other tkinter stuff from other threads, but apart from that, everything seems to work OK.  I have seen some sites that say tkinter can only be run in the main thread.

**EDIT:** I think I have a solution - use `after_idle` instead of `after`.  This seems to make sure that the callback isn't called until the mainloop is ready to process events, but can anyone confirm this?  Anyway, what is the point of `after` if you can't guarantee that tkinter will be fully set up when the callback is called (unless `after` is called in another event handler, I suppose)?

A concrete example of the effects of using `after` and `after_idle` in this case if anyone wants to play around with it:

```
import tkinter
import threading

#create a threading.Event for blocking until the mainloop is ready
mainloop_started = threading.Event()

#counter stores the number of times that tkinter receives the event
#<<increment>>, which is generated 1000 times
counter = 0

#delay in milliseconds before mainloop sets mainloop_started:
#if I set this to 0, the final value of counter varies between 0 and 1000, i.e.
#some of the <<increment>> events may not be processed as expected
#if I set it to 1 or a larger number, the final value of counter is always 1000,
#so all events are processed correctly, and I can get the
#same behaviour by replacing after with after_idle below
delay_ms = 0

def send_events():
    global root

    #wait until mainloop_started has been set
    mainloop_started.wait()

    #send 1000 <<increment>> events
    for i in range(1000):
        root.event_generate('<<increment>>', when='tail')

    #send a <<show>> event
    root.event_generate('<<show>>', when='tail')

#run send_events in a thread
th = threading.Thread(target=send_events)
th.start()

#start tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

#when root receives the event <<increment>>, increment counter
def increment(event):
    global counter
    counter += 1
root.bind('<<increment>>', increment)

#when root receives the event <<show>>, print the value of the counter
def show(event):
    print(counter)
root.bind('<<show>>', show)

#instruct mainloop to set mainloop_started
root.after(delay_ms, mainloop_started.set)

#using after_idle instead causes all events to be processed correctly
#root.after_idle(mainloop_started.set)

#finally, start the mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't dare to run anything tkinter related in somewhere else than main thread, I tried but it crashed in one of my computers. Then I decided that event_generate in secondary thread is safe, but even this caused me trouble when I needed to create a Toplevel. "event_generate" inside "after_idle" seemed to work, but I wasn't sure anymore, so I changed my plans (used polling instead of events)

Comment: @Aivar  Your comment is way too **subjective**.  Is it or is it not possible to call `.event_generate` from a thread? This is fear mongering.